# How to get IP address of US colleges?

Tags: ip-address, ip

I have a list of US colleges and I tried to get accurate IP address for all of them. Any place I can search?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to [wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org)
2. Enter the name of the college you want
3. Find the URL for the campus web page
4. Open up a command prompt/terminal
5. Type `ping (url from above)`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looking for this? It will be very difficult as there are many providers and they subclass their IP ranges.

Some schools may not have a publically defined block of IP addresses.

You could try contact ARIN [link](https://www.arin.net/) for information to start. It is doubtful there is a concrete list anywhere of all of these though as they change frequently enough that it would require a massive effort to maintain.